# Empty Label para un campo con ModelChoiceField

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms

Hola tengo un formulario (en Django 1.8) con un campo que usa un `ModelChoicefield`:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    campoA = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=ModeloB.objects.values_list('campoA__name', flat=True).distinct(),
        label=_('Campo A'),
        required=False)
    ...
```

Este se muestra de la siguiente forma:

[image: imagen]

Me gustaría 2 cosas:

1. Que no aparezca la opción `None`.
2. Que pueda cambiar la opción `'------'` por otra como `'Seleccione Ciudad'`.

**Editado**

Solucioné la parte 2 con la definición del `empty_label`, podrían ayudarme con la primera duda? para que no se vea la opción `None`?

Answer (score 1):

Comprueba que en la base de datos probablemente tengas un None en el campoA del ModeloB. Si no quieres borrar ese registro siempre puedes exluirlo:

```
queryset=ModeloB.objects.values_list('campoA__name', flat=True).exclude(campoA__name=None).distinct()
```